# Why does my camera lens only work with a Polaroid .43x lens?

Tags: lens, dslr, wide-angle-converter

I got a brand new Canon Rebel T6i and along with it came an ef-s 18-55mm lens, and a Polaroid studio series .43x wide angle lens (which I believe is a telephoto lens). The camera worked fine, but after I put the Polaroid lens on the 18-55mm lens, the 18-55mm lens is completely out of focus, and only acts normally with the Polaroid lens on. Is this normal? Would a factory reset on the camera do anything?

Comment: I'm a bit confused--first you say that with the Polaroid converter on, the lens is completely out of focus, then you say that it only acts normally with the Polaroid lens on it. Do you mean it only works **without** the Polaroid lens? Or **with** it?

Comment: Hasn't this exact question been asked before?

Comment: I mean to say that It only works with the lens

Comment: How close are you attempting to focus? Both with and without the add on lens?

Comment: with the lens on, I can focus around the normal range, but with it off, I can only focus about an inch away

Answer (score 2):

The Polaroid lens is a "secondary"  lens,  meant to screw to another lens (which is presumably what you did) . It isn't a telephoto lens — it's a wide-angle converter. You can tell this because the multiplier is less than one - it makes the focal length of the combination only 0.43× of. The focal length of the main lens. These are mostly a gimmick — they tend to reduce image quality more than anything.

But, there's no reason that this should cause any effect on autofocus — perhaps you accidentally bumped it into manual focus. Make sure it's switched to AF. Wider angle tends towards more depth of field — more in apparent focus — so that may be why it seems fine when you put the secondary lens back on.

Comment: I switched the lens to auto focus, But it's still blurry. I looked through the viewfinder while the camera was off, and it was still blurry, getting clear when I put the secondary lens on.

Comment: Is it just the viewfinder, or actual photos? Next step: check the viewfinder diopter adjustment.

Comment: No, unfortunately its the viewfinder and the actual photos. I did find that it is  clear very close up (about an inch away) which led me to try to change the aperture after the auto focus didn't work, hasn't changed it.

Comment: Hmm. Can you post an example? What if you *do* focus manually? I guess it's possible that you actually damaged the lens — one inch away is well under the normal minimum focus distance for this lens.

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzr4bEcaIz_NZG9BaXVNeng1dW8&usp=sharing Here's some pictures and a video I took

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you switched the 18-55mm lens to manual focus mode. There's a switch on the side with 2 positions labeled "AF" and "MF". Switch it to "AF" for auto-focus. "MF" stands for "Manual Focus" and allows you to adjust the focus manually with either the fine focus or gross focus rings.

[image]